# JUnit inheritance using BaseTest

Tags: java, maven, oop, junit, mockito

Hi I want to use base test that some test will extand .
here is my base

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class BaseOmsUnitTest {

  @BeforeClass
  public static void setUpBeforCalss() throws Throwable{
    JunitUtils.mockIlSession();
    OMSDomainsMocker helper = new OMSDomainsMocker();
    helper.mockOMSDomainConnection();

  }

  @Test
  public void dummyTest(){

  }
}
```

As you can see I want that every class that will inherit this base test will have the same init I also deliberately add the @RunWith annotation as the init need this runner. but when I run the tests with maven its without putting a dummyTest its gives me
*No tests found in Base
Haven't you forgot @Test annotation?*

Can I overcome this without using this dummyTest

Comment: Just rename your base class to something that doesn't end with Test.

Answer (score 6):

Just make your base class abstract